# Cassandra SSTable, Space Usage, Memtable size is 0 although table has some data

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I created a table with ~20 columns and ~100 rows. I can see everything as 0 in terms of space while querying space usage of the table.
It returns data upon querying.

**Other tables** in the same keyspace have numbers in 'Space used' or 'Memtable data size' fields.

Cassandra version 3.0

```
SSTable count: 0
    Space used (live): 0
    Space used (total): 0
    Space used by snapshots (total): 0
    Off heap memory used (total): 0
    SSTable Compression Ratio: -1.0
    Number of partitions (estimate): 0
    Memtable cell count: 0
    Memtable data size: 0
    Memtable off heap memory used: 0
    Memtable switch count: 0
    Local read count: 0
    Local read latency: NaN ms
    Local write count: 0
    Local write latency: NaN ms
    Pending flushes: 0
    Percent repaired: 100.0
    Bloom filter false positives: 0
    Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
    Bloom filter space used: 0
    Bloom filter off heap memory used: 0
    Index summary off heap memory used: 0
    Compression metadata off heap memory used: 0
    Compacted partition minimum bytes: 0
    Compacted partition maximum bytes: 0
    Compacted partition mean bytes: 0
    Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
    Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1
    Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
    Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1
    Dropped Mutations: 0
```

Comment: Can you run nodetool flush in the node then check the space in server.

Comment: I tried that. It still returns exactly the same result. Isn't 'nodetool flush' moves Memtable to SSTable/disk? If yes, then my Memtable has 0 size.

Comment: okay, just take a restart then run above cfstat command.